# cocos2d-x: Change audio playback rate

Tags: audio, cocos2d-x

I'm looking to set the playback rate of an audio file. Is there any way to do this for both iOS and Android? I could fork the repository and set it up myself, but I'm hoping to avoid that as it could take some time.

I'm currently using cocos2d-x v2.2.2.

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean 'set the playback rate'? Like slow the audio down or speed it up?

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean. It's fairly straightforward for iOS, but Android I believe is a bit trickier.

Answer (score 0):

Since `Cocos2d-x v2.2.2` has no such API for changing playback rate. Check API for [SimpleAudioEngine](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/reference/native-cpp/V2.2.2/de/d8f/class_cocos_denshion_1_1_simple_audio_engine.html#details) :

And you don't want to write your own code. Therefore simple answer is you can't change playback rate. You might try newer version Cocos2d-x v3.0 beta or you have to write your own code using API's provided by respective platforms.

Comment: SimpleAudioEngine doesn't offer it. I have ended up forking the repository anyway (for a number of reasons) and I can now implement a solution, if you can help me with that.

Comment: I don't think you need to fork the code of cocos2dx repository. Simple way to do is write bridge function or JNI calls using separate interface.

Comment: Android uses a SoundPool object. How can I access that without forking?

Comment: you miss understood  my point. Instead of changing default libraries comes with cocos2dx, you can write wrapper classes or interfaces without modifying original source code so that it can be easily used with different projects.